# Fresh Jekyll Install on Sierra OS

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I have never installed Jekyll before, this is my first time. 
I went through the process of installing xcode, ruby version 3.2.1 installed, jekyll version 3.2.1 installed. All of this is was freshly installed in the last 2 days.
When I go to localhost:4000 I get the content of the default jekyll page, but none of the style. It looks like this:
[Unstyled Default Jekyll Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78BaP.png)
Here is what the file structure looks like, I have not changed any file at all since installing. [File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1kYU.png) 
When I inspect the page it gives this as its css link as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/main.css">
```

I am at a loss of how to continue. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css is a bit messed up because the domain is wrong in the _config.yml. You can remove the example url and it’ll work nicely.

Should look like this.

`baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site`

If you get a domain you can update then.

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned in the comment below, this is now fixed and set by default in Jekyll 3.3.0.

When you generate a new site the css should link-up properly and the relevant section of the `_config.yml` will look like this:

```
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com
```

Comment: This bug has been fixed in version 3.3.

Comment: @DirtyF thanks for pointing out. I've tested with a new Jekyll build to confirm and updated my answer for newer versions.